# Why Chrome displays unexpected result when performing inheritance in ES5 syntax?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Why this code displays `LivingEntity` when executed in Chrome?

```
//During construction
var LivingEntity = function(location){
    this.x = location.x;
    this.y = location.y;
    this.z = location.z;
    this.moveWest = function(){
        this.x--;
    }
};

var Dragon = function(location){  
    /*
     * <Function>.call is a method that executes the defined function,
     * but with the "this" variable pointing to the first argument,
     * and the rest of the arguments being arguments of the function
     * that is being "called". This essentially performs all of
     * LivingEntity's constructor logic on Dragon's "this".
     */
    LivingEntity.call(this, location);
    //canFly is an attribute of the constructed object and not Dragon's prototype
    this.canFly = true;
};

/*
 * Object.create(object) creates an object with a prototype of the
 * passed in object. This example will return an object
 * with a prototype that has the "moveWest" and "makeSound" functions,
 * but not x, y, or z attributes.
 */
Dragon.prototype = Object.create(LivingEntity.prototype);

/*
 * If we didn't reset the prototype's constructor
 * attribute, it would look like any Dragon objects
 * were constructed with a LivingEntity constructor
 */
Dragon.prototype.constructor = Dragon;

/*
 * Now we can assign prototype attributes to Dragon without affecting
 * the prototype of LivingEntity.
 */
Dragon.prototype.fly = function(y){  
    this.y += y;
}

var sparky = new Dragon({  
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
});

console.log(sparky.__proto__);
```

I thought that this was enough to perform complete inheritance:

```
Dragon.prototype = Object.create(LivingEntity.prototype);
Dragon.prototype.constructor = Dragon;
```

But it looks like it's not, why?

Comment: It's an implementation-dependent console thing. Your code is still going to work as desired.

Comment: This is an internal implementation detail (though it is specified by newer specs of ECMA262). The spec merely says that the interpreter needs to show which object does this object's prototype come from and this is fully correct depending on the point of view of the brower/interpreter developer. Why do you think the inheritance is not working? Neither you nor anyone else should depend or look at `__proto__`. Instead use `instanceof` if you want to query the object's type